# Change the behaviour of ibidem (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to change the behaviour of replacing citations with *ibidem*.

If there is a series of multiple citations of one particular work, all of them after the second citation are replaced by “ibid.”. I would like to replace the citations after the third (or *n*-th) occurrence.

I use `biblatex` with the option `citestyle=authoryear-ibid`.

The following code generates the following output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}           

\usepackage{blindtext} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Surname.2009, 
   author = {Mary Surname}, 
   year = {1999}, 
   title = {Title}, 
   address = {City}, 
   publisher = {{Publisher}} 
} 
\end{filecontents} 

\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-ibid, natbib=true, ibidtracker=context]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document} 

She writes `Quote' \citep[264]{Surname.2009}, and  `Quote' \citep[23]{Surname.2009}, and `Quote' \citep[431]{Surname.2009}.

\printbibliography   

\end{document}
```

[image: test]

I would like to have *ibid.* only one time in the last citation. Is there a possibility to access the counter in the `biblatex` package?

Comment: Crosspost: https://golatex.de/anpassung-von-ebd-ibidem-in-biblatex-t21988.html I was just getting ready to think about an answer ...

Comment: I suppose you want the last citation in `sigfridsson` `worman` `sigfridsson` `sigfridsson` to come out as "Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998" and not as "ibid." right? What about `sigfridsson` `sigfridsson` /page break/ `sigfridsson` `sigfridsson`? Does the second `sigfridsson` on the second page become "ibid." or "Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998"?

Comment: @moewe Yes. I wish for an outcome just as you described. My favourite option is to reset the counter with any new page. However, I think this is controlled by the option `pagetracker` (cf. p. 59 in the documentation). If the reset is too difficult, I am happy with a solution that ignores page breaks.

Comment: @moewe, there's a whole new set of tracker commands for you ;). `\ifciteseenxtimes`, etc.

Comment: Still looking into this. Unfortunately, things didn't quite work out as I hoped, so I have to rethink my strategy.